# Add default value for null column in laravel yajra table

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

I use laravel `yajra/datatables` in my order model there is a one to many relations between driver and order in some cases the `driver_id` becomes `NULL` in cases so what i want to do is to print a default value in case if there is no `driver` for this order here is my `OrderDataTable` file

**query** method

```
public function query()
{   
   return Order::select('id', 'client_name', 'phone', 'price',  'shipping_price', 'city_id', 'status_id', 'driver_id')
     ->with('city:id,name')
     ->with('status:id,name')
     ->with('driver:id,name')
     ->orderBy('id', 'desc');
}
```

**getColumns** method

```
    protected function getColumns()
    {
        return [
            Column::make('client_name'),
            Column::make('phone'),
            Column::make('Price')->data('price'),
            Column::make('Shipping')->data('shipping_price')->name('shipping_price'),
            Column::make('City')->data('city.name')->name('city.name'),
            Column::make('Status')->data('status.name')->name('status.name'),
            Column::make('Driver')->data('driver.name')->name('driver.name'), // this is the column that i want to add default value for
            Column::computed('action')
                  ->exportable(false)
                  ->printable(false)
                  ->addClass('text-center'),
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Should be able to do it via a renderer. [source](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables-html/blob/c663ea3478a027afde7d866b2f439259a1a2b47f/src/Html/Column.php#L447)

Comment: @KurtFriars thanks a lot for helping it fixed with `render` :)